# numbering items in regex

Tags: php, code-generation

I searched google for such solution but I couldn't find, I want to generate number beside each matched item, for example in emmet:
If I wrote the following in my IDE that supports emmet:

> ul>li.item$*5

It will generate:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1"></li>
    <li class="item2"></li>
    <li class="item3"></li>
    <li class="item4"></li>
    <li class="item5"></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same in Regex?

Thanx for your advice,

Comment: A regex is just a search pattern for strings. It doesn't "generate" anything.

Comment: I want to replace the beginning of the line with numbers

Comment: The beginning of what line? What language(s) are you using to generate your HTML, or where are you expecting to write your regular expression? PHP? JavaScript? Post more of your code.

Comment: I have an example to generate number in html, but I'm talking about generating numbers in php strings

Comment: If it's php you use, perhaps change the question and tags to php. Since this can surely be done via php code. But regex normally won't have a counter variable that can be used in the replace string.  In such case it's normally the programming language where regex is used that will do the counting or it uses the array returned from the regex match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a list with PHP you can use a simple loop, you don't need regex.

```
<ul>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) : ?>

    <li class="item<?= $i; ?>"></li>

    <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```